# Tranferir a imagem de um controlo Image para outro do mesmo tipo

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Tenho estes três controlos:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" />
<Image x:Name="imagem01" />
<Image x:Name="imagem02" />
```

Vamos supor que carrego uma imagem em "**imagem01**" utilizando:

```
OpenFileDialog ofdImage = new OpenFileDialog();
ofdImage.Filter = "JPEG Files|*.jpg|Bitmap Files|*.bmp|Gif Files|*.gif";
ofdImage.DefaultExt = "jpg";
ofdImage.FilterIndex = 1;
if (ofdImage.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    this.imagem02.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofdImage.FileName));
}
```

Qual é o código devo escrever, associado ao botão "**btn**", de forma a carregar em imagem02 a mesma imagem que tenho em "**imagem01**".

Answer (score 0):

Arghh ... não acredito que era tão simples:

```
imagem02.Source = imagem01.Source;
```